# Warden not accessing the database (Devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, warden

Rails 3.2. Hi. Currently out app has an authentication system implemented that we did and we are going to migrate to devise. I am at wits end here trying to get the devise log in to work. Somehow I have drilled down the problem to the part where Devise actually creates a user session.

```
def create
  self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
  set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_flashing_format?
  sign_in(resource_name, resource)
  yield resource if block_given?
  respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
end
```

Routes (I have changed the devise controller and literally just pasted the Devise controller code to debug it with pry):

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: "sessions" }
```

The problem here is that warden is not even hitting the database with an `authenticate`. It just returns `nil`. I checked my other, simpler application and `authenticate`'s behavior scans the database, regardless if email/password is correct. How do I get Warden/Devise for that matter to actually do a select statement to check the database out?

(If there is anything I can paste to help you guys I'll paste it)

Comment: What does your "devise" member in your model look like?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am running in to the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

In case it may help someone else: I was running into this very same problem. The source of the trouble turned out to be that I had a custom app/views/sessions/new.html.erb view that was *not* copied from devise.

See https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/3700 for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try look in console the authentication keys of your devise model:

```
(your_model).authentication_keys
```

If result is different respect keys you need (i.e email), just add explicity in your model:

```
:authentication_keys => [:email]
```

I resolved in this way. Hope this help

Bye