# Devise DatabaseAuthenticatable not accessing database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am having the same problem as [Warden not accessing the database (Devise)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22933966/warden-not-accessing-the-database-devise) -- I am integrating Devise into a Rails 4.0.5 application. I've followed all the instructions to the letter.

However, when I attempt to log in, I can tell from stepping through in the debugger that Warden isn't even trying to query the database. As far as I can tell it thinks the :database_authenticatable strategy is invalid.

Can anyone shed light on this? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: digging further, I used the debugger to force-run the strategy and I can see that the error message it would generate is " @message=:not_found_in_database," - however, it's not even hitting the database!

Comment: Trust, but verify -- link to your repository, please?

Comment: @hd1it is unfortunately a private repo which I can't share, sorry. If you let me know which details will help you I'm happy to share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I had a custom view which was causing a problem -- link to discussion with Devise core maintainers here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/3700